# How do I prevent texture stretching while texture painting in blender?

Tags: texture-painting

So im texturing an animal thing I made, and when painting it, it looks fine:[image]

However, when you look at if from any other angle, it is extremely distorted, because of the way the mesh curves from the perspective i'm painting from:[image]

So my question really is, is there anyway to paint a texture from the perspective of the UV map (without painting directly *on* the UV map)? or should I just spend more time being careful while texturing this to make sure this is no stretching?
(Sorry if this is terribly explained or if I am wrong about anything, i'm new at this kind of stuff)

Comment: Have you tried using procedural texture brushes to arrive at something similar? I ask because with procedurals, then you can use the 3d mapping instead of mapping the brush to View, and then it will evenly wrap along the surface of the mesh. I will look if there are any other ways to get around this, as I usually use Stencil mode and try to softly paint in with the x axis mirror on, and get the edges to align manually.